# algorithms and complexity book

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

All,

I am a mid level python developer with a master's degree in Web Technologies, and while I consider my self a decent programmer, I always have trouble with algorithm complexity related questions.

Anyone suggest a good book to explain how to derive the O notation of an algorithm, and what common solutions to complex algorithms can be used?

I am currently reading "Uncle Bob's" The Clean Coder: A Code of Conduct for Professional Programmers (a well worth read by the way, I highly recommend it), and in it he dedicates a chapter to explain how spending 20 hours outside of work a week improving your craft is the only way to become a better programmer.  So I thought I'd start with algorithm complexity and move to Big Table and Closure afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation Wikipedia for the win.

Comment: Compete in programming competitions and learn algorithm complexity the hard way. Then, you'll never forget!

Comment: most of the time Ive found that simplicity and readability matter more in python than picking the absolute best algorithm ... there are always exceptions but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) by Thomas Cormen seems to be the go-to manual for the industry. It covers a wide range of topics including sorting, data structures, advanced design and analysis, and graph algorithms.

> Introduction to Algorithms uniquely combines rigor and comprehensiveness. The book covers a broad range of algorithms in depth, yet makes their design and analysis accessible to all levels of readers. Each chapter is relatively self-contained and can be used as a unit of study. The algorithms are described in English and in a pseudocode designed to be readable by anyone who has done a little programming. The explanations have been kept elementary without sacrificing depth of coverage or mathematical rigor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically looking to get a strong hold on asymptotic analysis then watch these two video lectures. For asymptotic analysis this is much much better than reading `CLRS`

[CS61B UCBerkeley Lecture 19](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIS4YDpuP98)

[CS61B UCBerkeley Lecture 20](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca3e7UVmeUc)

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of Algorithms, Jeffrey McConnell, very simple book: [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763707821)

Answer (score 0):

There are many books to learn algorithms. Here is a good discussion about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302270/what-is-the-best-book-for-learning-about-algorithms

Depending on your current level of understanding and time you have you can pick one.